# Java 1.8 refuses to parse dates with US/Aleutian (HAST) time zone?

Tags: java, parsing, timezone, timestamp, datetime-format

I am trying to parse a US/Aleutian timestamp. This has worked in the past, and I couldn't find out why it is no longer working. I'm running Java 1.8 update 72.

The code is as follows:

```
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Aleutian"));

        // the following line throws an parsing exception
        Date d = sdf.parse("1969-12-31T13:00:00HAST");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(d));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

... the `Date d = sdf.parse("1969-12-31T13:00:00HAST");` line throws an exception, but I cannot find out what's wrong with it:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1969-12-31T13:00:00HAST"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
```

I am certain that this has worked in the past. I researched the HAST time zone, and it is valid. I'm not sure why this isn't working for me.

Can anyone find out what's going on? If this works for you, can you please list your java version so we can find out if/when this got broken?

Thanks!

Comment: `TimeZone.getTimeZone("HAST")` now returns GMT, which according to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone-java.lang.String-) indicates the requested TimeZone ID was not understood.  I don't know why HAST is no longer accepted.

Comment: Wow! That's weird... I'm not sure then, it seems like a bug in Java itself. But a strange one. Why would this be removed?! o.O

Comment: I recommend to use the id instead of the synonym: `America/Adak` (instead of "US/Aleutian") whenever possible.

Comment: @MenoHochschild great catch!! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer.

According to [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html), that abbreviation was removed in Java 6 update 101:

"The abbreviations for Hawaii-Aleutian standard and daylight times have been changed from HAST/HADT to HST/HDT, as per US Government Printing Office style. This affects only America/Adak since 1983, as America/Honolulu was already using the new style."

So I'll go ahead and use HST instead.

Thanks for the input everyone!

Answer (score -1):

SimpleDateFormat is an old class that has some problems. Try using class java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter that is new class in Java 8. Try something like this:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz");
    Instant instant = formatter.parse("1969-12-31T13:00:00HAST", Instant::from);
    Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

Comment: The issue is that I'm passing SimpleDateFormat to Jackson, the JSON library. It uses SimpleDateFormat internally. I could perhaps try to find a way to get Jackson to use something else to parse, but my use cases are complicated and that'd mean performing an open heart surgery on Jackson. If I could find out what's going on with SimpleDateFormat and have this parse correct there, it'd be much better.

Comment: Actually for JSON you should format your date to String and feed JSON just strings. Meaning get your date format it into a String of the format that you want and feed it to your JSON

Comment: It is a string. The input is something like `{ "date": "1969-12-31T14:00:00HAST" }` . I use Jackson to parse this, and Jackson takes an old school ` DateFormat` to customize the format of dates in the JSON being parsed. Therefore my need to have SimpleDateFormat handle this timezone.